# AWS EKS NodeCreationFailure

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

Following the [AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html) on creating an [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks) cluster, I get this error:

```
NodeCreationFailure Unhealthy nodes in the Kubernetes cluster
```

I followed the required IAM roles for both the cluster and the nodegroup. Also tried using Private and/or Public subnets. The error does not appear in their documentation as well so I am unable to troubleshoot this further